# Laravel: Attempt to read property "id" on bool - Nested loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have problem with looping child of categories `hasMany`. I have column i db with `parent_id` and relation

I have a problem when I want to do a nested loop under the category of the parent category. I keep getting this error:

> Attempt to read property "id" on bool

I separated the loop into another file and using the `import' function I tried to create a recursive file that will display all child levels

When i remove `@include` in loop everyting works fine but only show parent categories.

Here is my code.

**Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'parent_id', 'content_before', 'content_after', 'slug', 'meta_title', 'meta_description'];

public function childrens()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BlogCategory::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

**Controler**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $categories = BlogCategory::where('parent_id', '')->paginate(10);

    return view('ecommerce::admin.blog_category.index',[
        'categories' => $categories
    ]);
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<tbody>
@forelse($categories as $category)
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ route('blog_category.edit', $category->id) }}" style="font-weight: 500 !important;">{{$category->name}}</a></td>
        <td>{{$category->created_at->format('d.m.Y')}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ route('blog_category.edit', $category->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @if(count($category->childrens))

        @include('ecommerce::admin.blog_category.loop.parent_categoriest_loop', ['childrens' => $category->childrens])

    @endif
@empty
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">0 records.</td>
    </tr>
@endforelse
```

**parent_categoriest_loop.blade.php**

```
@foreach($childrens as $child)
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ route('blog_category.edit', $child->id) }}"><span style="font-size:12px">——</span> {{$child->name}}</a></td>
        <td>{{$child->created_at->format('d.m.Y')}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ route('blog_category.edit', $child->id) }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    @if(count($child->childrens))
        @include('ecommerce::admin.blog_category.loop.parent_categoriest_loop', ['childrens' => $child])
    @endif
```

@endforeach

Answer (score -1):

i think that is the problem

**parent_categoriest_loop.blade.php**

replace $child to $child->childrens

```
        @include('parent_categoriest_loop', ['childrens' => $child->childrens])
```